# How are hardware interruptions handled in non-preemtive scheduling?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, process, linux-kernel, operating-system

Let's say I have a process A that is currently running. Then I press Ctrl+C, how is this interruption handled?

Does A finish executing first and then the interruption is handled?

Does A get put in the ready queue?

Comment: Did you mean Crtl+Z/C ?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I meant Ctrl+C.

Comment: Non-preemptive scheduling?  Are there any OS.that still cling to such a design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing interrupts, signals and task scheduling. Those are all very different concepts.

> I press Ctrl+C, how is this interruption handled?

CTRL+C has *nothing* to do with interrupts. It's a key combination that is intercepted by your terminal emulator, which then sends a signal (`SIGINT`) to the currently running process. Signal delivery is done through the [`kill`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) syscall (which, contrary to its name, does not necessarily kill the process).

> Does A finish executing first and then the interruption is handled?

What happens when your program receives a `SIGINT` signal depends on the specific case. A program can *register a signal handler*, and decide what to do in case it receives a specific signal. In other words, this "interruption" as you call it, happens *while the process is running*: when the signal is delivered, the kernel will temporarily "pause" the normal process code, let the process run its signal handler, and then resume the process from where it left.

A process can only register handlers for signals that are catchable (`SIGINT` is). The only two signals that are uncatchable in Linux are `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`. In case the process has not registered a signal handler, the default handler defined by the kernel will do its job: for `SIGINT`, the default handler just terminates the process.

[**See `man 7 signal`**](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for more information.

> Does A get put in the ready queue?

There is no such thing as a "ready queue", I suppose you mean [*runqueue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_queue). If the process gets killed by the signal, then it will cease to exist and will be removed from its runqueue, therefore no runqueue will have A anymore.

If the process is *not* terminated, it will still exist in the system, and the kernel will keep executing it along with other processes that are executing on the same CPU. There is one runqueue per CPU, and the scheduler uses it to determine which processes to run when. Processes can also be moved from one runqueue to another (for example for load balancing purposes), but this is a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

In x86 interrupts are disabled and enabled with CLI (clear interrupt flag) and STI (set interrupt flag) commands respectively. 
 [Non-maskable interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-maskable_interrupt) will not be affected by it though. Other interrupts will be served as soon as you set interrupt flag back again.

The terminal in which you hit Ctrl-C sends an INT signal to all processes attached to it, ("interrupt", SIGINT) which by default, this causes the process to terminate.